# How to build a comparison operator (comparitor) in an arithmetic circuit

Tags: math, logic, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic, circuit

I am trying to convert a basic program into an arithmetic circuit. I am stuck on the step of converting the greater than operator into an arithmetic circuit. To be specific, I do not know how to convert the following into an arithmetic circuit (where x,y is input):

`if x >= y:
    return 1
else:
    return 0`

To be clear, I need to be able to express this in terms of an ARITHMETIC circuit. Meaning that I need to be able to compute this using only addition and multiplication of numbers (in Z_p).

I've been searching all of the web for solutions, but everything I find tells me how to do this with boolean circuits. I am aware that I can convert the numbers into their bit string and do this boolean way. I would like to know of any alternative way to do this. This show be possible to do with just addition and multiplication, but I cannot figure out how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any circuit if you use the proper coding for your data. The best and most widely used to code signed integers is [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).
Positive numbers are coded by their binary code and a negative number A<0; is rendered positive by considerig 2^n-|A|=2^n+A where n is the number of bits n the code.

Two's complement has (at least) two main advantages.
The first one is that it largely simplifies arithmetic operations. For instance, as a negative number A is coded arithmetically by 2^n+A, one does not have to care about the sign of operands, provided bit over 2^n are ignored, and adding signed    numbers is identical to adding unsigned.

A second advantage is that  positive numbers are in the range 0..2^(n-1)-1 and always has their most significant bit unset. Negative numbers are in the range -1..-2^(n-1). Once added to 2^n the range of their code is 2^(n-1)..2^n-1 and corresponds to number with the most significant bit set. So, to know if a number is >=0, it is just required to test its most significant bit.

So there is no real "circuit" or arithmetic operator to do that. In a program, this can be done by computing an "and" with the MSB.

```
int is_positive(int x) { return (x & (1<<31)) == 0 ); }
```

There is no way to express it only with arithmetic operations without either an and, an or or a comparison. And you must have a way to detect if a number is entirely at 0, which requires logic gates.